# Vagrant hangs on mounting folders for windows VM

Tags: ruby, vagrant, virtualbox, chef-solo, vagrantfile

I'm hoping someone could please help because I don't know how to solve this!

I'm using Vagrant and VirtualBox to run a Chef recipe. Essentially the recipe will create a user on a windows 2012 machine.

My problem is however when I type vagrant reload --provision (or any other vagrant command apart from halt),

the host machine does the following:-

```
D:\cookbook-core>vagrant reload --provision
==> default: Loading Berkshelf datafile...
==> default: Sharing cookbooks with VM
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> default: Forcing shutdown of VM...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Updating Vagrant's Berkshelf...
==> default: Resolving cookbook dependencies...
==> default: Fetching 'core' from source at .
==> default: Using apt (2.6.1)
==> default: Using chef-client (4.2.4)
==> default: Using chef_handler (1.1.6)
==> default: Using chocolatey (0.2.1) 
==> default: Using core (0.0.1) from source at .
==> default: Using cron (1.6.1)
==> default: Using hipchat (0.4.0)
==> default: Using hostsfile (2.4.5)
==> default: Using logrotate (1.8.0)
==> default: Using minitest-handler (1.3.2)
==> default: Using ms_dotnet2 (1.0.0)
==> default: Using ms_dotnet4 (1.0.2)
==> default: Using ms_dotnet45 (2.0.0)
==> default: Using ohai (2.0.2) from git@github.com:JustGiving/cookbook-ohai.git (at master)
==> default: Using powershell (3.0.7)
==> default: Using sudo (2.7.1)
==> default: Using sysctl (0.6.2)
==> default: Using users (1.7.0)
==> default: Using windows (1.36.6)
==> default: Vendoring apt (2.6.1) to c:/Users/aebirim/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20150312-3420-1mj6gii-default/apt
==> default: Vendoring chef-client (4.2.4) to c:/Users/aebirim/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20150312-3420-1mj6gii-default/chef-client
==> default: Vendoring chef_handler (1.1.6) to c:/Users/aebirim/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20150312-3420-1mj6gii-default/chef_handler
==> default: Vendoring chocolatey (0.2.1) to c:/Users/aebirim/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20150312-3420-1mj6gii-default/chocolatey
==> default: Vendoring core (0.0.1) to c:/Users/aebirim/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20150312-3420-1mj6gii-default/core
==> default: Vendoring cron (1.6.1) to c:/Users/aebirim/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20150312-3420-1mj6gii-default/cron
==> default: Vendoring hipchat (0.4.0) to c:/Users/aebirim/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20150312-3420-1mj6gii-default/hipchat
==> default: Vendoring hostsfile (2.4.5) to c:/Users/aebirim/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20150312-3420-1mj6gii-default/hostsfile
==> default: Vendoring logging (0.0.1) to c:/Users/aebirim/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20150312-3420-1mj6gii-default/logging
==> default: Vendoring logrotate (1.8.0) to c:/Users/aebirim/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20150312-3420-1mj6gii-default/logrotate
==> default: Vendoring minitest-handler (1.3.2) to c:/Users/aebirim/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20150312-3420-1mj6gii-default/minitest-handler
==> default: Vendoring ms_dotnet2 (1.0.0) to c:/Users/aebirim/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20150312-3420-1mj6gii-default/ms_dotnet2
==> default: Vendoring ms_dotnet4 (1.0.2) to c:/Users/aebirim/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20150312-3420-1mj6gii-default/ms_dotnet4
==> default: Vendoring ms_dotnet45 (2.0.0) to c:/Users/aebirim/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20150312-3420-1mj6gii-default/ms_dotnet45
==> default: Vendoring ohai (2.0.2) to c:/Users/aebirim/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20150312-3420-1mj6gii-default/ohai
==> default: Vendoring powershell (3.0.7) to c:/Users/aebirim/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20150312-3420-1mj6gii-default/powershell
==> default: Vendoring sudo (2.7.1) to c:/Users/aebirim/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20150312-3420-1mj6gii-default/sudo
==> default: Vendoring sysctl (0.6.2) to c:/Users/aebirim/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20150312-3420-1mj6gii-default/sysctl
==> default: Vendoring users (1.7.0) to c:/Users/aebirim/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20150312-3420-1mj6gii-default/users
==> default: Vendoring windows (1.36.6) to c:/Users/aebirim/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20150312-3420-1mj6gii-default/windows
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
GuestAdditions versions on your host (4.3.12) and guest (4.3.8) do not match.
The guest's platform is currently not supported, will try generic Linux method...
Downloading VirtualBox Guest Additions ISO from http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.12/VBoxGuestAdditions_4.3.12.iso
Progress: 100% (Rate: 20.5M/s, Estimated time remaining: --:--:--)
Copy iso file C:/Users/aebirim/.vagrant.d/tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions_4.3.12.iso into the box /tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
/bin/sh: sudo: command not found
Installing Virtualbox Guest Additions unknown - guest version is 4.3.8
/bin/sh: sudo: command not found
/bin/sh: sudo: command not found
Cleaning up downloaded VirtualBox Guest Additions ISO...
bash.exe: warning: could not find /tmp, please create!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /tmp/vagrant-chef/7ceb72d4e097eb60d8a5bb90970df99d/cookbooks => C:/Users/aebirim/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20150312-3420-1mj6gii-default
```

This is my vagrantfile:-

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "win2012"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://box.dev.ju.service/win2012.box"
  config.winrm.username = "vagrant"
    config.winrm.password = "vagrant"  
    config.vm.guest = :windows  
    config.windows.halt_timeout = 15
    config.ssh.insert_key = false

 config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
  vb.gui = true
end

      config.vm.provision :chef_zero do |chef|
      chef.log_level                           = :info
      chef.data_bags_path                      = 'data_bags'
      #chef.provisioning_path                   = '/tmp/vagrant-chef-2'
      #chef.environment                         = 'dev'
      chef.encrypted_data_bag_secret_key_path  = "D:/tmp/vagrant-chef-2/encrypted_data_bag_secret"
          chef.run_list = [
          "recipe[users]",
          "recipe[core::default]"
        ]
        end

end
```

The VM gets launched but as you can see from the output, Vagrant hangs permanently on mounting a shared folder (even when I disabled mounting according to the docs) and doesn't go past this part therefore chef-solo is not provisioned and my chef recipe isn't run. I'm running Vagrant 1.7.2 with VirtualBox 4.3.12. The VM I'm trying to create is a Windows 2012 box.

Comment: Answer to this question...be careful about where you pull down your vagrant box from. I was using a vagrant box that turned out to be flawed which lead to the VM loading getting stuck at the mounting of the shared folder stage. The mounting of the shared folders is essential otherwise vagrant will not be able to access data on the hosted machine.